# Event Observer on the orders grid if someone selects an order and uses one of the actions in the drop down menu items

Tags: orders, event-observer, order-comment

If someone selects and order by checking the box and then using one of the action items in the dropdown. I would like to add the user and timestamp and the action item they selected to the comments section of that order. Primarily just for auditing purposes.

[image: Order Selection]

[image: items action selection]

[image: leave comment]

Is there a module out there that does this already or no? If anyone could point me in the direction to start which event do i need to hook into with my observer that would be great. Need a bit of help getting this started.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you have to possibilities.

1. There are a lot of admin logger extensions. Some of them are even free to use. Check google for something like "magento 2 admin logger". You should easily find one, which can at least log the actions. But i don't know if you can filter them like you want to do.
2. Build this yourself. Afaik there is already an order action log (or at least there should be a comment when you ship an order) existing, and you could hang yourself in at this point.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both ideas. I was thinking about trying to hook into the existing comment section just never done this before.